# PrestaShop - Display shipping price and subtotal on shipping page

Tags: prestashop, checkout

I am using

```
{displayPrice price=$total_price_without_tax}
{displayPrice price=$total_price}
```

on the cart and payment pages, but it doesn't work on the shipping page, it returns nothing. Is there a way to display those values on all checkout pages ?

Also,

```
{displayPrice price=$total_shipping_tax_exc}
```

works on the cart page but not the checkout nor the shipping ones... Can I fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variables are not generated in that page, the easy way to create it inside a smarty template is:

```
{assign var="total_price_without_tax" value=Context::getContext()->cart->getOrderTotal(false)}
{assign var="total_price" value=Context::getContext()->cart->getOrderTotal()}
```

And now you can use as normally:

```
{displayPrice price=$total_price_without_tax}
{displayPrice price=$total_price}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ! Do you know how to get the shipping price with the same method ?

Comment: Of course, with this code you can get the shipping price with tax incl. `{Context::getContext()->cart->getTotalShippingCost()}`, and with this code you can get it with tax excl. `{Context::getContext()->cart->getTotalShippingCost(null, false)}`.

Comment: Thanks, you're great.